# Tensorflow trained model works on cloud machine but gives an error when used in my local pc

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've tried to create a custom object detector in the `paperspace` cloud desktop, then I tried it on `Jupyter Notebook` and it works.

Now, I've uploaded the whole `models-master` folder and downloaded it on my local machine.

I ran it using `Jupyter Notebook` and it now gives an `InvalidArgumentError`. I've tried re-exporting the inference graph on my local machine using the same ckpt that was trained on cloud but it is still not working.

> InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1322     try:
>   -> 1323       return fn(*args)    1324     except errors.OpError as e:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options,
>   run_metadata)    1301                                    feed_dict,
>   fetch_list, target_list,
>   -> 1302                                    status, run_metadata)    1303
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py
>   in **exit**(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
>       472             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
>   --> 473             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>       474     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
>
> InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef mentions attr 'T' not in Op index:int64>; NodeDef:
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/FilterGreaterThan/Where
>   = WhereT=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0".
>   (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with
>   your GraphDef-generating binary.).     [[Node:
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/FilterGreaterThan/Where
>   = WhereT=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        20       (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
>        21           [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
>   ---> 22           feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
>        23       # Visualization of the results of a detection.
>        24       vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>       887     try:
>       888       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
>   --> 889                          run_metadata_ptr)
>       890       if run_metadata:
>       891         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>   1118     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and
>   feed_dict_tensor):    1119       results = self._do_run(handle,
>   final_targets, final_fetches,
>   -> 1120                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)    1121     else:    1122       results = []
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options,
>   run_metadata)    1315     if handle is None:    1316       return
>   self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
>   -> 1317                            options, run_metadata)    1318     else:    1319       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session,
>   handle, feeds, fetches)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1334         except KeyError:    1335 
>   pass
>   -> 1336       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)    1337     1338   def _extend_graph(self):
>
> InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef mentions attr 'T' not in Op index:int64>; NodeDef:
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/FilterGreaterThan/Where
>   = WhereT=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0".
>   (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with
>   your GraphDef-generating binary.).     [[Node:
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/FilterGreaterThan/Where
>   = WhereT=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>
> Caused by op
>   'Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/FilterGreaterThan/Where',
>   defined at:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in
>   _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       app.launch_new_instance()   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
>   line 658, in launch_instance
>       app.start()   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py",
>   line 477, in start
>       ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py",
>   line 177, in start
>       super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py",
>   line 888, in start
>       handler_func(fd_obj, events)   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py",
>   line 277, in null_wrapper
>       return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
>   line 440, in _handle_events
>       self._handle_recv()   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
>   line 472, in _handle_recv
>       self._run_callback(callback, msg)   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
>   line 414, in _run_callback
>       callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py",
>   line 277, in null_wrapper
>       return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py",
>   line 283, in dispatcher
>       return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py",
>   line 235, in dispatch_shell
>       handler(stream, idents, msg)   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py",
>   line 399, in execute_request
>       user_expressions, allow_stdin)   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py",
>   line 196, in do_execute
>       res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)   File
>   "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py",
>   line 533, in run_cell
>       return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2728, in run_cell
>       interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)   File
>   "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
>       if self.run_code(code, result):   File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2910, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 7, in 
>       tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py",
>   line 313, in import_graph_def
>       op_def=op_def)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2956, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1470, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): NodeDef mentions attr
>   'T' not in Op index:int64>;
>   NodeDef:
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/FilterGreaterThan/Where
>   = WhereT=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0".
>   (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with
>   your GraphDef-generating binary.).     [[Node:
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/FilterGreaterThan/Where
>   = WhereT=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]

Comment: maybe you use tensorflow-gpu in the cloud but on your computer, you use  tensorflow cpu

Answer (score -1):

Are the cloud and local machines running the same Python/Tensorflow versions? Sometimes checkpoints produced by a specific Tensorflow version are not backward compatible due to internal variables renaming.